# Are Parity/author and Geth/coinbase the same?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

Am I right that what geth calls the coinbase is the same thing that parity calls the author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's called `--etherbase` in **Geth**:

```
--etherbase value       Public address for block mining rewards (default = first account created) (default: "0")
```

And for **Parity** it's `--author` but `--etherbase` will work too:

```
--author ADDRESS               Specify the block author (aka "coinbase") address
                               for sending block rewards from sealed blocks.
                               NOTE: MINING WILL NOT WORK WITHOUT THIS OPTION.
                               (default: None)
--etherbase ADDRESS            Equivalent to --author ADDRESS.
```